# Window closes immediately after being created (and shown) in a sepatarted thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, window, sta

I was trying to instantiate and show a Window, when I got an exception saying `{"The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this."}` so I re-did it all in a separated STA thread as follows :

```
var thread = new Thread(() =>
{
     notificationPopUp = new NotificationPopUpView(unreadNotifications.First().session_s,unreadNotifications.First().secondry_msg);
     notificationPopUp.Show();
});

thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
```

Now the window shows and then goes away immediately, I suppose that is because the thread terminated its work so than the object declared within died as well, well if I'm correct, how should I deal with this, I tried to avoid this solution by putting the `[STAThread]` attribute before the `Main` method, before the owner method, before many other methods (desperately) but I continued to have the same problem, I know the Title of the question is somehow not well descriptive, but I'm kinda obliged to mention this STA thing, here's the error I used to get before creating the thread (just to provide you with the whole data) :

[image]

So **my principle question** is : Why is the window closing immediately ?

Now if because it's because it's created in the thread and it gets disposed after the thread finishes working, what should I do knowing that I should keep respecting the STA Thread caller ? thanks in advance.

Comment: If you search for this error message on SO, you will find that it has been answered numerous times

Comment: @thumbmunkeys : I know, but I couldn't ensure it was targeting my specific case, so I didn't really understand the answers to those questions, considering I did my best searching on SO and on Google, and considering I'm a beginner, and posting the question here was my sole refuge, knowing that I'll receive comments such as yours, would you understand all that and help me solve the problem ? 

thank you in all cases ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you have created a window in new thread, and the thread terminates, then who is going to run the [message loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows)?

A thread, which created a user object(Window, Form, Control) must run its message loop to respond to the messages sent by the operating system.

Call [Dispatcher.Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.run%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to run the message loop.

```
var thread = new Thread(() =>
{
    notificationPopUp = new NotificationPopUpView(unreadNotifications.First().session_s,unreadNotifications.First().secondry_msg);
    notificationPopUp.Show();
    Dispatcher.Run();
});
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.IsBackground = true;
thread.Start();
```